# Photo Gallery with mouse navigation

Tags: navigation, cursor, mouse, image-gallery, photo-gallery

I'm trying to build a photo gallery that uses the mouse to navigate through the images,where the cursor changes when you hover left, center, or right. on click of left or right of the image the images changes to the next image. click the center and it returns to the thumbnails. much like this one:

http://design54.cmdwebsites.com/

I've got the gallery all setup and ready to go, but where do i start with the mouse? Basically what I am wanting is when the mouse is on the right side of the window the cursor is a right arrow, move the mouse to the left side and the cursor changes to a left arrow and when it is in the middle the cursor is different again. These changes in the cursor will indicate to the user that they can click for the next picture (or previous).

Comment: Are you asking about the technology to do it? If yes, you have 2 possibilities, using the HTML events or javascript, the javascript will be better in your case as HTML cant provide miniature showing, only taking to the other page. If this is not the case you will need to be me more specific in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "miniature showing" but basically what I am wanting is when the mouse is on the right side of the window the cursor is a right arrow, move the mouse to the left side and the cursor changes to a left arrow and when it is in the middle the cursor is different again. These changes in the cursor will indicate to the user that they can click for the next picture (or previous).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK that's clearer.

[Cross Browser CSS cursor Images In Depth](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/12/21/cross-browser-css-cursor-images-in-depth/)

Here they show you how to change the cursor image when over an element.

---

*You are being very general here...
**A good place to start is here: [Javascript Image Slider](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider)**
Demo 4 is kind of what you need, just get rid of the bottom navigation and make the scrolling buttons transparent.
Keep in mind that the site you brought is proffesional-level.*

Comment: I thought I was being specific, but I'm not concerned with the slider aspect, I can do the slider. It is the mouse aspect I'm trying to accomplish. Basically what I am wanting is when the mouse is on the right side of the window the cursor is a right arrow, move the mouse to the left side and the cursor changes to a left arrow and when it is in the middle the cursor is different again. These changes in the cursor will indicate to the user that they can click for the next picture (or previous).